# Drupal Text Field with Tokens

Tags: drupal, textarea, nodes, content-type

I created a content type. In content type I created a text field(current page), in which in default value I want to show the current page of node. I have tokens installed. The token I'm using is [node:url]. Then I create the content type (using default value of text field) and instead of showing URL of Node, it displays : [node:url]

Why isn't think working? I read about Token Filter for text area's. Enabled the module, still will not show URL of Node in newly create node. I'm using Drupal 7.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, on my content type i don't see anything as node:url.
Instead, i see [current-page:url]
See if that does anything.